# Serving gzip files in React server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, gzip

I'm having trouble actually serving a gzip compression of my bundle.js file in React. I am trying to reduce the size of this dramatically, and I have done uglify and dedupe, etc ... and it's gone down from 2.9mb to 2.6mb which is really weird to me. I am now using the compression plugin and I get an outputted gzip file, but now I'm still serving the bundle.js and not the bundle.js.gz.

I don't want to use the compression middleware from express, because I'm doing the gzip in the build process. Anyways, here is my distServer file:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();


app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*.js', function(req, res, next) {
 req.url = req.url + '.gz';
 res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
 next();
});

app.get('*.css', function(req, res, next) {
 req.url = req.url + '.gz';
 res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
 next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

And my webpack config is:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

export default {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: '"production"'}
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      mangle: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
        pure_getters: true,
        unsafe: true,
        unsafe_comps: true,
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' },
      { from: 'src/sitemap.xml', to: 'sitemap.xml' }
    ], {
      copyUnmodified: true
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, [/moment$/]),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css?sourceMap")},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "url?limit=10000"},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {
        test: /favicon\.ico$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 1,
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I thought the app.get functions would bring in those gzip files as needed, but I might be missing a step? Also, in my index.html file, do I need to omit the script tag bringing in the bundle file all together?

Any guidance and thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Use the compression middleware https://github.com/expressjs/compression

Comment: I wrote above that I don't want to use compression middleware because I'm building out the gzip in the build phase.

Answer (score 3):

You should put your static listing after the middleware

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();


app.get('*.js', function(req, res, next) {
 req.url = req.url + '.gz';
 res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
 next();
});

app.get('*.css', function(req, res, next) {
 req.url = req.url + '.gz';
 res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
 next();
});

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you first want to verify if you even are serving the gzipped files, which is easily done through Chrome DevTools.

Open up Chrome DevTools, go to the `performance` tab and profile your website. After it's loaded, check the network requests section and find the Javascript files you want to verify are being gzipped. If done correctly, you'll see [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uo40.png), where the `encoded data` is the size of the (hopefully compressed) data sent over the wire, and the `decoded body` is the size of the uncompressed data.

**If the two are equal, then you could be gzipping correctly, but not sending it over.**

My recommendation to you is to handle this at a reverse proxy level, ideally with the [NGINX gzip static module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html) to serve the gzipped files. You really should be using NGINX to serve static content anyway, as it will take load off of your node server.