# When using html-webpack-plugin, is there any way to reference a .js.gz file in the script tag?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

With my React app, I have bundle & vendor files that are 100-200 KB large, and I gzip them to reduce size. While using html-webpack-plugin, however, the only scripts referenced in the `<script>` tags are the .js files. Instead of referencing the js files, is there any way to get html-webpack-plugin to reference the bundle.js.gz files?

Comment: Note: HTTP already supports compression in a way widely supported by both servers and clients. You should be able to reference bundle.js and get the same savings.

Comment: @hvd Whenever I check the network tab, the size of the file is still the same as it was on the server. Do I need to add some express middleware or change settings to see this effect? Thank you for enlightening me to this feature!

Comment: How to enable it depends on the server you're using. You mention Express, in which case it is covered in [Production best practices: performance and reliability: Use gzip compression](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-gzip-compression).

Comment: [Visit here, you can get the right answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931156/serving-gzip-files-in-react-server)